# Mule Missing Authentication Methods in drop down

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, request, mule

In Mule AnyPoint Studio after I created an HTTP Request and go to Authentication tab I only have the options: None and NTLM

I am missing: Basic, OAuth and OAuth2 like in this example. I am using the Community Edition but I doubt that this is the cause of the missing options.
Do I need to add some mvn dependencies to see these?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/authentication-in-http-requests

Comment: are the oath and request tags really appropriate here?

Comment: I understand your frustration but yes that is what is missing in the IDE and the whole problem :D

Comment: Okay this is definitely a bug in Anypoint Studio when you set your project to be compiled for a CE you are only left with Basic and NTLM. When you create a project for EE than the other options are there.
You can create this in XML using (don't forget the xsd and namespace) and it will compile and run just fine on CE.

Comment: does not sound like a bug. in works in ce, because you probably stil have the ee-jars in your classpath inside of Anypoint.

Comment: No, I checked the Pom no dependencies to ee artefacts.